# Postman does not accept `-` as an URI param for mocking server requests

Tags: unit-testing, request, mocking, postman

I get the following error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "mockRequestNotFoundError",
        "header": "No matching requests",
        "message": "Double check your method and the request path and try again."
    }
}
```

When I pass `-` as an URI param for a Postman request created via a mocking server unlike when I pass the same URI param value in a request not created via a mocking server it's working well!

URL: `http://{{host}}/order/{{subUserId}}/{{BusinessDate}}/5`

host: `{mocking-server-url-without-http-keyword}`

subUserId: `1`

BusinessDate: `2020-01-12-17-07-21`

HTTP request header: `x-api-key` : `{{postman_secret_API_key}}`

The main request by using the mocking server as a host which returns data correctly:

[image]

The mocked request by using the mocking server as a host which returns an error:

[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with the full URI, please? Are there any other headers that you're using in the examples or the request?

Answer (score 3):

The mock `example` would need to match the path of the main request for it to be returned.

For example:

[image]

If it doesn't, it wouldn't be able to find the mock `example` that you're using:

[image]

I'm unsure of your particular context but you could also use different `Request Headers` on your main request to point to specific mock examples:

```
x-mock-response-code:200
x-mock-response-name:<name of the mock example>
```

Comment: I am using the same path for the main request and the mocked response while the problem in passing this char `-` in URI because when I replace it with `/` I get the mocking data retuned successfully so it maybe a bug in `Postman`.

Comment: I had no problem using that character in the requests that I was making so their might be also something else that you're doing. Without any more details about the full request, it would be difficult to help. If you want to raise a question on the Postman community forum I would be able to help you more. community.getpostman.com

Comment: Do you send Postman API Key as an HTTP header `X-Api-Key` in your test case? https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/postman-api/intro-api/

Comment: If the mock is private (you would have had to choose that option when you created the server) then you would need to use the `x-api-key` header.

Comment: Yes I've already made the mocking server as a private and by using the generated API Key I get the main requests working well except when I use `-` with the mocked request it is not working but when I use `-` for the main request I get it working. I think this issue maybe occured because the mocking server contains `-` involved.

Comment: What's the value of `{{host}}`? Does that also contain `https`? Not sure why you would need the `http` value that you have.

Comment: `host` contains only url without `http`

Comment: Just try this scenario with yourself by using a private mocking server with `x-api-key` http header key-value because I think it's a bug.

Comment: I've created a topic on community.getpostman.com https://community.getpostman.com/t/postman-does-not-accept-as-an-uri-param-for-mocking-server-requests/10107

Comment: Can you confirm that you have no _new line_ characters in the Environment file - You wouldn't see this when you hover over the variable name. I've recreated the scenario locally and I can make it do what you're seeing when it has a new line. The variable will look like `2020-01-14-09-00-00...` in the Manage Environment section.

Comment: Environment file has no new line for any key-value param.